How can I find the logs for a failing k9s plugin load?
I am currently experimenting with k9s plugins and my current plugin configuration is failing with a pink message in the upper right hand corner saying K9S Plugin load failed!. I'm having trouble debugging the failure because I'm not sure where to look for logs or a traceback. Do you know if any debugging information exists and where it might be found?
Thanks!

I have same issue and that problem is still not solved - https://github.com/derailed/k9s/issues/2651
As you can see from other comments from link, alternative way is to use:
k9s --context ..

For logs, you can use command:
k9s info  # Get info about K9s runtime (logs, configs, etc..)

I using Windows and for me is:
C:\Users<Username>\scoop\persist\k9s\logs\k9s.log

I got the same issue - "plugin load failed" for one of my contexts. In the folder C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\k9s\clusters there is a folder for each context. I removed the folder corresponding to the cluster having the issue and then retried in k9s and now it worked fine.
(Perhaps not an answer to "how to debug..." but it resolved my issue with "plugin load failed")
